# How to classify text with an estimator?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, text-classification, countvectorizer

I trained estimator with this:

```
def train_estimator(feature_list, expected_values, k=5):
    pipeline = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(input='filename', stop_words='english')),
                         ('clf', MultinomialNB())])

    parameters = {'vect__ngram_range':[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
                  'vect__min_df':[0.001, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1],
                  'vect__max_df':[0.85, 0.90, 0.95, 0.99, 1.0],
                  'clf__alpha':[0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0]}

    gs_clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=6, cv=k, verbose=1, refit=True, scoring='roc_auc')
    gs_clf.fit(feature_list, expected_values)

    return gs_clf.best_estimator_
```

Now I need to classify some text with this estimator, but its not clear how to vectorize the text properly.

I need to vectorize `text` and then call `estimator.predict()` with the vector. The thing is, this vector must agree with the vectors used to train `estimator` (the word `foobar` must have the same index as the vectors used to train the model). Its not clear from the documentation how to vectorize `text` in such a fashion.

How do I write this `predict()` function?

```
def predict(estimator, text):
    # Vectorize text and call estimator.predict()
```

**EDIT**

`feature_list` and `expected_values` were made as follows:

```
def fetch_training_set(doc_iterator):
    files, labels = list(), list()
    for row in doc_iterator:
        filename = 'somepath/%s.txt' % random()
        with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(row['text'])

        files.append(filename)
        labels.append(row['label'])

    feature_list = np.array(files)
    expected_values = np.array(labels)

    return feature_list, expected_values
```

Comment: What is `feature_list`? Raw texts?

Comment: @Vivek Kumar `feature_list` is a list of file names. Each file contains text.

Comment: @Vivek Kumar `feature_list` is actually an `np.array()` of file names. I updated the question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding your extra functions `train_estimator` and `predict` makes things complex.

```
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=6, cv=k, verbose=1, refit=True, scoring='roc_auc')
gs_clf.fit(feature_list, expected_values)
gs_clf.predict(your_data)
```

will do the job (last line). Since you refit (`refit=True`) your pipeline, `gs_clf` is refit with the best parameters the grid search found. Then, `gs_clf.predict` will call the `predict` functions of each member of your pipeline your pipeline.

Comment: what's `your_data`? is it text or a feature vector?

Comment: normally text. But since the input of your CountVectorizer is filename, I  should try a filename also.